# Google Static Maps URL length limit

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I have 153 markers and need to generate a static map with them, but when put them in the url I get an error like this:

```
414 Request-Uri Too Large
```

My url is something like this

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=13.00,-85.00&size=600x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=13.305,-86.18636&markers=13.72326,-86.13705&......"
```

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This response came from the Server (google). So you're not allowed to request such long URLs.

See the google api doc for more infos:

> Static Map URLs are restricted to 2048 characters in size. In practice, you will probably not have need for URLs longer than this, unless you produce complicated maps with a high number of markers and paths.

Comment: and what if you need to generate an image with a high number of locations? (ie if I wanted to generate a polygon representing several US counties)

Comment: I am so tired of people's smart-ass, pointless answers.  Why did this answer get upvoted?  OBVIOUSLY there are maps out there with more points than can fit in a URL.  This is NOT an answer.

Comment: @Hill Answer and upvote can be faked. You know that most of the thing you can see is fake out instead of real one :D

Answer (score 20):

The way i see it is either you **reduce precision** of your markers in order to gain space in the URL. 
    (i.e. markers=13.72326,-86.13705---->markers=13.73,-86.14)     resulting in placing the markers in a grid...
Or you go with a non static api

Comment: This is what I ended up doing - rounding in PHP using precision to the 6th decimal really shortened things up for me.

Answer (score 6):

### Officially you can use 8192 characters

This depends on [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) and server, but as a thumb rule 8192 characters should be OK.

#### Server

Google Maps Static server https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap at **30 July 2019**.

[Google Static Maps Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#url-size-restriction) claims that:

> Maps Static API URLs are restricted to **8192 characters** in size. In practice, you will probably not have need for URLs longer than this, unless you produce complicated maps with a high number of markers and paths. Note, however, that certain characters may be URL-encoded by browsers and/or services before sending them off to the API, resulting in increased character usage.

But **in practice**, I'm getting errors (413 Payload Too Large) after 15k~ characters mark (**30 July 2019**):

```
╔═════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Browser ║ Browser Version ║ Valid URL Length ║
╠═════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Chrome  ║ 75              ║            15489 ║
║ Firefox ║ 68              ║            15761 ║
║ Safari  ║ 12.1            ║            15690 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

This is based on data got by using `fetch()` in browser console. I'd assume that Google Static Maps server accepts requests (whole request, not just path) no larger than 16k in size.

### Solutions

#### Reduce Precision

Our company policy is that coordinate data below [6 decimal places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees#Precision) (111.32 mm) is useless (considering our market share uses phones and commercial GPS devices).

```js
const decimalPlaces = 6 // decimal places count
const decimalPowered = 10 ** decimalPlaces // 1_000_000
const trim = number => Math.round(number * decimalPowered) / decimalPowered // function that trims number
const coordinates = [
  [51.838245, -111.834991],
  [51.8331, -111.835],
  [51.831007022306, -111.8232751234],
  [51.838244686875, -111.82327418214]
]
const trimmedCoordinates = coordinates.map(coordinate => coordinate.map(trim))
console.log(trimmedCoordinates)
```

#### Encode coordinates

If you have access to encoder you can replace path with an encoded path (use `String` manipulation instead of `URLSearchParams`, because `searchParams` automatically uses encodeURI, which would break your encoded path):

```js
const coordinates = [
  [51.838245, -111.834991],
  [51.8331, -111.835],
  [51.831007022306, -111.8232751234],
  [51.838244686875, -111.82327418214]
].map(([lng, lat]) => ({ lng, lat }))

// path should be MVCArray<LatLng>|Array<LatLng>, if you have Polygon or Polyline, getPath() method should be fine
const path = coordinates.map(coordinate => new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate)) 

const encoded = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(
  path
);

return (
  url.href +
  `&path=fillcolor:${color}|color:${color}|enc:${encoded}`
);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Encoding

#### Handle Errors

- Use placeholder image
- Check if `href.length > 8192` before request
- Trim coordinates
- Encode path
- Check if `!res.ok && res.status === 413` and display error for user which claims that map is too detailed
- Use fallback image

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem,

i used link like this, 
and reduced position precision:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=61.52401,105.318756&zoom=2&size=710x400&markers=|59,30|48,44|55,37|55,37|55,37|56,44|56,60|55,49|47,39|57,39|55,37|55,82|47,39|55,37|53,50|51,36|55,37|54,73|45,38|48,44|50,43|46,44|51,42|56,53|59,32|59,30|60,30|59,30|59,28|59,32|59,29|58,31|68,33|56,92|59,38|57,56|55,37|55,36|55,38|55,37|55,38|56,38|55,38|51,46|55,38|45,41|53,49|55,61|50,36|50,36|55,48|55,48|55,49|56,50|56,47|53,91|47,39|57,61|44,37|56,86|55,43|44,41|43,13|43,13|42,13|42,13|57,61|64,40|46,48|55,45|52,47|56,43|54,19|53,83|48,40|54,54|53,58|54,83|59,56|52,85|48,13|55,55|50,12|51,40|56,43|49,40|59,33|37,34|58,33|53,34|54,42|56,30|58,54|54,33|56,60|58,60|57,46|43,44|56,40|49,36|49,32|47,42|59,39|56,35|51,39|55,38|57,45|55,42|56,43|56,43|57,13|56,43|56,44|55,42|55,44|55,42|55,43|54,43|54,44|54,43|56,44|55,45|55,43|57,45|56,43|55,44|57,46|56,45|57,53|60,28&sensor=false

Comment: How did you do this?  I can't find out how to manipulate the link being generated by the polygons.

Answer (score 4):

You can encode your Polylines and make them shorter .

**Here is the example which can help you how to short your Polylines**

I am using the php library to short the length 
here is the link of library https://github.com/danmandle/encoded-polyline-stitcher

if you use this library

```
(51.838245,-111.834991|51.833179,-111.83503|51.831007022306,-111.8232751234|51.838244686875,-111.82327418214)  =  (atk{HtwqiTt^FpLmhAgl@)
```

Here important point is if you use short url you have to use **"enc:"** keyword

```
(fillcolor:0xAA000033|color:0xFFFFFF00|51.838245,-111.834991|51.833179,-111.83503|51.831007022306,-111.8232751234|51.838244686875,-111.82327418214)  =   (fillcolor:0xAA000033|color:0xFFFFFF00|enc:atk{HtwqiTt^FpLmhAgl@)
```

**The Library is available for other  languages as well if you are not using php  .**

I hope that it helps others

Answer (score 3):

Google recently extended the URL limit to [8192](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#url-size-restriction), but if you need more than that, you still need to simplify your map or resort to other [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375885/6770969).

Answer (score 2):

URLs over 2000-ish characters aren't valid. Is your querystring longer than that?

Also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url)

Answer (score 1):

You might also use marker clustering on a static map:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/php_google_maps/cluster.html

http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/11/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

Very old thread but I had to cobble together something to tackle this very problem in a hurry. Sharing here in case anyone else had the same problem.

It takes an array of markers in the form:

```
$points =
        [0] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 52.1916312
                [lng] => -1.7083109
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 50.2681918
                [lng] => 2.5616710
            )
            ...
            ...
            ...
        [500] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 49.1821968
                [lng] => 2.1671056
            )
```

Max url length is 2048 chars so it first reduces accuracy of the lat lng to 
$marker_accuracy (4) then starts removing markers from the middle. 
Removing markers from the middle could be improved a lot as it does
it one at a time

```
$map_url = make_static_map($points);

function make_static_map($points,$reduce_len=false,$reduce_count=false){
    $grp_points = array();
    $grps = array();
    $url = array();
    $max_len = 0;
    $width = 640;   //max 640 :(
    $height = 640;  //max 640 :(
    $marker_accuracy = 4;   //Lat lng to 4 decimal places minimum, 3 would be less accurate

    $url[] = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?';
    $url[] = '&size='.$width.'x'.$height.'&scale=2';
    $url[] = '&markers=';

    if($reduce_count){  //Last resort to shortening this
        array_splice($points, ceil(count($points)/2), 1);
    }

    foreach($points as $i => $point){
        if($reduce_len){
            $point['lat'] = number_format($point['lat'], $reduce_len, '.', '');
            $points[$i]['lat'] = $point['lat'];
            $point['lng'] = number_format($point['lng'], $reduce_len, '.', '');
            $points[$i]['lng'] = $point['lng'];
        }else{
            $t_len = max(strlen($point['lat']),strlen($point['lng']));
            if($t_len>$max_len){
                $max_len = $t_len;
            }
        }
        $grps[] = array($point['lat'],$point['lng']);
    }
    $grps = remove_duplicate_points($grps);
    foreach($grps as $grp){
        $grp_points[] = implode(',',$grp);
    }
    $url[] = implode('|',$grp_points);
    $url[] = '&sensor=false';
    $url = implode('',$url);
    if(strlen($url) > 2048){
        // Bugger, too long for google
        if($max_len>$marker_accuracy){
            // Reduce the length of lat lng decimal places
            return(make_static_map($points,$max_len-1,false));
        }else{
            // Reduce the number of lat lng markers (from center)
            return(make_static_map($points,false,true));
        }
    }else{
        return($url);
    }
}


function remove_duplicate_points($points){
    $points = array_map('serialize', $points);
    $points = array_unique($points);
    return(array_map('unserialize', $points));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use osm-static-maps, it's a clone of google static maps but you can send any amount of data to it. https://github.com/jperelli/osm-static-maps

Disclaimer: I'm the author.