# Google Static Map API multi polygon url too long

Tags: ruby, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am working with Static google maps to generate urls with multi polygons on the map. But the coordinates are very long and the urls exceed 8 thousand characters.

Here you have the url that i use with 2 polygons:
[static map](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0.04096,41.65521&zoom=15&size=1200x800&path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7C0.03990083369766674,41.65117297365802%7C0.03986585098450487,41.6511738730363%7C0.0398193071116094,41.65118861345209%7C0.03978640897789055,41.651211227828185%7C0.039785212880236676,41.65121205009294%7C0.039761889395081365,41.65124414021116%7C0.03975127958141444,41.65127097990489%7C0.03973309671778063,41.65131697476312%7C0.039706482497244025,41.651425988964064%7C0.03969658765996025,41.65146652049745%7C0.039683272167788275,41.65150292059053%7C0.03968380609505212,41.65151410540278%7C0.03968455879000179,41.6515298809837%7C0.03969278143750318,41.65153853529924%7C0.03969588944738445,41.651541805918015%7C0.03971376972429572,41.65156062329174%7C0.039752407785648564,41.65158215221135%7C0.03979465677110295,41.65160350427274%7C0.03988602119749911,41.651632606242316%7C0.03992955596697664,41.65164948823451%7C0.03993958742929026,41.65165619711021%7C0.039968351608118506,41.651675434417314%7C0.03999355934521909,41.651701840766634%7C0.04000585559790465,41.65173745966629%7C0.04000155651951174,41.65177364266802%7C0.03998752269819514,41.65181002432095%7C0.03993384247251406,41.65191499844431%7C0.0399064931590255,41.65198778102845%7C0.03987869457550017,41.65209657478536%7C0.03987154648804941,41.65213727647139%7C0.03986267424301351,41.65216458136081%7C0.039847923768933036,41.65220997439829%7C0.03980755819723356,41.65227854926681%7C0.03978735697119576,41.65231062932676%7C0.0397695957173166,41.65234709479867%7C0.039757844288369676,41.65238344543852%7C0.03975297859328857,41.65242411611149%7C0.03975461138812371,41.65245838049552%7C0.039754692692589313,41.652460093756645%7C0.03976241996958375,41.65249586520693%7C0.039775312175620324,41.65253159055675%7C0.039792208417040606,41.65257165102716%7C0.0398126778639959,41.65260712072893%7C0.03984532034965278,41.652678297340344%7C0.039888420936520154,41.652749203216246%7C0.039899750755712435,41.652784978019326%7C0.03990246230155005,41.65282539304425%7C0.03990100971764384,41.65284035977143%7C0.03989973315371473,41.652853510978275%7C0.03989900644266644,41.65286150731441%7C0.03988340855812481,41.65289793925871%7C0.03982299431103434,41.65300310029855%7C0.03980279308499652,41.653035180358444%7C0.039796679324458795,41.65304764676378%7C0.03978491196989489,41.653071643315826%7C0.0397440929372068,41.65317631904341%7C0.0397286140756973,41.65321275350229%7C0.03970857042944851,41.65324925082547%7C0.03966616386420511,41.6533061086308%7C0.03966059408921564,41.6533135760688%7C0.03962721818698753,41.653337031149846%7C0.039608159414420085,41.65335700606448%7C0.03959644067489746,41.653369288906106%7C0.039574675385634625,41.65340141925745%7C0.03955691413175548,41.653437884729385%7C0.03954504200339567,41.653474232016464%7C0.03952742659464041,41.65350945529025%7C0.03952465972823856,41.65351498818487%7C0.03951080444147017,41.653542693729264%7C0.03949758031204822,41.6535615806728%7C0.03948831998487233,41.6535748056404%7C0.03938851917243118,41.65370353659338%7C0.039367413538987255,41.65375064205381%7C0.039358610025561444,41.653770290912405%7C0.039341569615398024,41.653808324638504%7C0.03932925156976292,41.65384916294957%7C0.039294849722525456,41.653976004621455%7C0.03927882436089661,41.65403509285139%7C0.03927713624549725,41.654056445750996%7C0.03927596780812548,41.65407122304717%7C0.039281407663608055,41.65410711603502%7C0.039310323554892744,41.654178376465495%7C0.03936399288409906,41.65425614795873%7C0.039382605739391195,41.65428311924833%7C0.03939218541709694,41.654297000518994%7C0.0394054858218423,41.65431627386832%7C0.03942630395599031,41.65434644117781%7C0.039450928312595376,41.6544222747749%7C0.03945708817360331,41.65445818620299%7C0.039456164487818746,41.654516564485675%7C0.03945594907289441,41.654530202681144%7C0.039453803305554584,41.65455188918051%7C0.03945192324456115,41.65457089514709%7C0.03943704788011598,41.65460725500702%7C0.03941627919919963,41.65464382357635%7C0.03934394253232732,41.654732627331185%7C0.0393319027658941,41.654747407980096%7C0.039311307590383746,41.65477269199252%7C0.03926260956824479,41.6548369987957%7C0.03925610688737672,41.65484747114613%7C0.03921995489865273,41.65490569352545%7C0.03921109941742416,41.65492864736862%7C0.0392059194009554,41.6549420751783%7C0.03919861708647711,41.65497826991475%7C0.03919375139139601,41.65501894058772%7C0.039193012107492216,41.655039557556165%7C0.03919245806365955,41.655055020492085%7C0.03919789791914211,41.655090913479995%7C0.03921464077172523,41.65512646783898%7C0.03923784355746767,41.65515732497917%7C0.03926289874392143,41.65517922521707%7C0.03928896814071942,41.655192054558825%7C0.03933606186649572,41.65518633390957%7C0.0394175440284636,41.655148178645845%7C0.039442782778607764,41.65513278192702%7C0.03945621058828894,41.65512459029256%7C0.039527098862206865,41.65506869053877%7C0.039586379037730636,41.65501163156773%7C0.039623324792732284,41.654976069665025%7C0.039725422246779336,41.654896838882365%7C0.03976381052740279,41.654868829913084%7C0.03980034640731491,41.65485428311925%7C0.039848573366467556,41.654835081854316%7C0.039941219385935034,41.654810092046716%7C0.039994916375423455,41.6547901758054%7C0.04003271457002846,41.654776157071524%7C0.04003523752303347,41.65477534486507%7C0.04007854095196967,41.65476139737734%7C0.04011864668465535,41.654737845904435%7C0.040155591601466624,41.654709888902886%7C0.040182720470888646,41.654686606489065%7C0.040188089918380375,41.654681998118434%7C0.040242230310573,41.65462206415444%7C0.04027888772808837,41.654571541391874%7C0.040315545145603725,41.6545210177911%7C0.04037410196284068,41.65445642432684%7C0.04040103721028788,41.65442415735046%7C0.040431813884187574,41.654391899594174%7C0.04046347317254383,41.65436398701678%7C0.04046785858454457,41.65436054037798%7C0.04047288018303395,41.65435659333954%7C0.040498973887352574,41.65433608282126%7C0.04050050609934366,41.65433434776722%7C0.04052434842433622,41.65430734714093%7C0.040555966641364495,41.65427153964842%7C0.04057773193062733,41.65423940929708%7C0.04060973320065338,41.65417113617707%7C0.04065305339339694,41.65410239115596%7C0.04065650087037687,41.6540996050112%7C0.04068771927060004,41.65407437631933%7C0.04072866319365282,41.65405084580112%7C0.040770455365357124,41.654027156026785%7C0.040860539036872326,41.65399777745441%7C0.040907804591673896,41.653983054640634%7C0.04095089763482795,41.65397290750806%7C0.04100058555979046,41.6539760792204%7C0.04104998095631486,41.65398824890633%7C0.04109435643073061,41.65400515185328%7C0.04114391192161512,41.65403052052292%7C0.04116956473780064,41.65404365328962%7C0.04119017248616651,41.65406561806819%7C0.04119417065421764,41.6541015638621%7C0.04119530388759398,41.65412534919008%7C0.04119588475351839,41.65413754066901%7C0.04120276964919386,41.65417338085089%7C0.04122281245725229,41.65419983413889%7C0.04124421732465728,41.654211061698874%7C0.04126361975527523,41.654221238168105%7C0.04131172601501501,41.654237967609646%7C0.04136353875255816,41.65424896382905%7C0.04138485477178423,41.65425348754249%7C0.04140638955869612,41.654258057356344%7C0.04145406834134867,41.65426576954596%7C0.04160685871060841,41.654275199187566%7C0.04165954987165629,41.65427835748889%7C0.04181220445407655,41.65426977106674%7C0.041937059614781114,41.65426650044793%7C0.04196128164000998,41.654265865937816%7C0.04198126661293308,41.65426063060079%7C0.04198913302952844,41.65425856949068%7C0.04198995948523041,41.654258353237566%7C0.04199706314859171,41.65425649161676%7C0.04201822074983839,41.654250948663844%7C0.04202009075254742,41.65425045916069%7C0.04202343094116037,41.65424958408994%7C0.042057054109546785,41.65424077554738%7C0.042151707594943494,41.65421124274798%7C0.04219497246712282,41.65419209345086%7C0.04220322026033522,41.65418708861617%7C0.04227241455152121,41.65414509695515%7C0.04227500791251706,41.65414385391884%7C0.042302370637051494,41.65413073875416%7C0.042353914315486796,41.6541248613633%7C0.042403152132222184,41.65413261378603%7C0.042413530605347784,41.654134562578605%7C0.042414217083258446,41.65413469165995%7C0.04243573091541116,41.65413873089932%7C0.042487086839204234,41.6541483734413%7C0.04250871131248541,41.654161268161914%7C0.04251341356044492,41.65417922052319%7C0.04249180752735182,41.65421576813779%7C0.04243910882259064,41.654275740658534%7C0.042402066675696765,41.6543058694113%7C0.04224077202697229,41.65443706045298%7C0.042230817678172446,41.654445157371924%7C0.042212416885043194,41.65446012326092%7C0.042203314137656336,41.654467526996456%7C0.042190945800599206,41.654477586957256%7C0.04216446569052133,41.65449912509689%7C0.042158375399313885,41.65450340238232%7C0.04212451502305359,41.65452718519583%7C0.04208356690904897,41.65455080623855%7C0.04195181511800379,41.65460378908983%7C0.04190542295756477,41.65462303729345%7C0.04185803335058887,41.654637846440835%7C0.04181464861718705,41.65465699238521%7C0.0416459468801884,41.6547380219244%7C0.041602715535623766,41.654761673980175%7C0.041584732161297336,41.6547697449152%7C0.0415343996679425,41.65479233414561%7C0.041517508455664424,41.65479991473927%7C0.041206645441451396,41.65492519234792%7C0.041072091580008956,41.654967805108015%7C0.041067007117242045,41.654969415271694%7C0.04098074475561051,41.65500777505386%7C0.0409415702524227,41.655031294675524%7C0.040926787088917914,41.655043202846116%7C0.04091264346466323,41.65505459552958%7C0.04090137650974849,41.65507725684432%7C0.04089677233006193,41.655086517171526%7C0.04089737917988772,41.65510847356819%7C0.04089776642383733,41.65512247553826%7C0.040903428399767176,41.65513149865757%7C0.04091724010063649,41.65515350702202%7C0.04094500934749897,41.655184301297936%7C%200.04096908636579433,41.65521968382788%7C0.04098133567981932,41.65523302865674%7C0.04105383830838432,41.65531201552599%7C%200.04109895139032312,41.655378379248276%7C0.04112916228572502,41.65541355977439%7C0.04115775631190874,41.65544364997035%7C%200.04118758834526468,41.65547504355237%7C0.04120909547189447,41.65548727945534%7C0.041225389892631165,41.65549654984082%7C%200.04127064379055165,41.655517888491175%7C0.04131000940114316,41.65553934616457%7C0.041343394523465304,41.655565511953284%7C%200.04137345119183965,41.65559618552976%7C0.04137836801653314,41.65560232024504%7C0.04139821468804566,41.65562708290304%7C%200.04142181226145102,41.65566441590201%7C0.04177131668977836,41.6555764746451%7C0.04208765141070791,41.65549688008781%7C%200.04280846076062087,41.655315512456184%7C0.04502639796742188,41.65475740088567%7C0.04503264248565688,41.65475582927874%7C%200.04491913726071341,41.65471054688234%7C0.04481832056154731,41.65463496222779%7C0.04490633893199795,41.65458509157733%7C%200.04516969080163186,41.654501499690184%7C0.0454428671005587,41.654456392475595%7C0.04567295370909296,41.65444145676145%7C%200.04576299295651871,41.65449938493592%7C0.04582947067272489,41.65455530648262%7C0.04584204604280269,41.65455214147582%7C%200.04669402212688459,41.6543377323799%7C0.04674658839756776,41.65432450405953%7C0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062%7C%200.04747183177452276,41.65406386792671%7C0.04745190379854463,41.6540552605498%7C0.04730123069815222,41.653990180935125%7C%200.04693486523240001,41.653832617071714%7C0.04660293514149995,41.653688814617794%7C0.046272875891499275,41.65354614120625%7C%200.04589455364016018,41.65338232192815%7C0.04559773953469034,41.65325319954027%7C0.04547678028281212,41.65320111690542%7C%200.04547537212299538,41.65320051089381%7C0.04545764355854056,41.65319287749412%7C0.04542093836417426,41.65317707257657%7C%200.0454185159940133,41.65317602902954%7C0.04540317375753365,41.653169423251285%7C0.04538960261729971,41.653163579388035%7C%200.04530522534580381,41.65312724886476%7C0.045198634353198666,41.65308073013756%7C0.044926965120551894,41.65296216727194%7C%200.044682048409852286,41.65285887288209%7C0.044474430332298885,41.65278022380352%7C0.04404397599288677,41.65262487360093%7C%200.043744324613024264,41.65251593567527%7C0.04336616161785493,41.652380391072825%7C0.04304298726352973,41.652263371315655%7C%200.04280758401349688,41.652177968937366%7C0.042621828455288904,41.6521115809075%7C0.042493676691870486,41.65206577967129%7C%200.04213919341276249,41.651937684904794%7C0.04190932641010441,41.65185728652298%7C0.04175594344025513,41.65180033484029%7C%200.041663035905393116,41.651765838277555%7C0.04139794143798598,41.65166988811163%7C0.041386050031247734,41.65166558400412%7C%200.04132406082445745,41.65164317163189%7C0.04112134448417094,41.651569877751626%7C0.041083383680634716,41.65155590847098%7C%200.040914122032470836,41.65149362003021%7C0.04079188789304423,41.65144863770598%7C0.04053546785774635,41.651355575105924%7C%200.04031697006922782,41.65127609705709%7C0.040218658721069014,41.65124693138503%7C0.040136785962390065,41.65122264230462%7C%200.04003391569682453,41.65119818390971%7C0.03995920862759403,41.6511804218176%7C0.03990083369766674,41.65117297365802%20&path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7C0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062%7C0.04674658839756776,41.65432450405953%7C0.04669402212688459,41.6543377323799%7C0.04584204604280269,41.65455214147582%7C0.04582947067272489,41.65455530648262%7C0.04595265951097963,41.65465893279591%7C0.04610042744355961,41.65482261628716%7C0.04614809197697591,41.654895094608236%7C0.045911219379229505,41.654906380003325%7C0.045561253108009875,41.65490780408874%7C0.045443292901265184,41.65490303143281%7C0.04522180361132643,41.654831294910224%7C0.04503264248565688,41.65475582927874%7C0.04502639796742188,41.65475740088567%7C0.04280846076062087,41.655315512456184%7C0.04208765141070791,41.65549688008781%7C0.04177131668977836,41.6555764746451%7C0.04142181226145102,41.65566441590201%7C0.0414310650449136,41.65567905489678%7C0.04144861088386839,41.65570681408536%7C0.041465396484160214,41.655733370470756%7C0.04149721083773439,41.655762378563%7C0.04149725945277568,41.65576451343384%7C0.04150375878088228,41.65605208229957%7C0.041496843710353594,41.656059615954575%7C0.041444482796310356,41.656116656485466%7C0.04141456275296585,41.656135429435096%7C0.04136614468640951,41.65614120624315%7C0.04132706825149465,41.65614227074488%7C0.04128124354593417,41.65612551029031%7C0.04119501722648842,41.65607768063336%7C0.04116495469078151,41.65606100567422%7C0.04112186332400818,41.656039632658064%7C0.04108033518226952,41.656018209350464%7C0.041008348878970674,41.655995706453695%7C0.040987399987125396,41.65598915767234%7C0.040937129519857736,41.655972462596594%7C0.040889723149074506,41.6559692598712%7C0.04078962477905301,41.65596289884451%7C0.04076305582079624,41.65595886211969%7C0.04074718720076604,41.65595645148423%7C0.0407389427603151,41.65595519838962%7C0.04072028045179132,41.65594841407679%7C0.04069311805475462,41.65593843793502%7C0.04065432325180311,41.65591240206584%7C0.04061847971713421,41.65588179722096%7C0.040587874034069424,41.65585566495989%7C0.04056173925842281,41.655836514824585%7C0.04055220568118726,41.65582952934605%7C0.04054751935884471,41.65582596871337%7C0.04051785663994292,41.655803428936224%7C0.0404244830712368,41.65571582798458%7C0.04030450534027847,41.655592959335024%7C0.04026526042909982,41.65557150501439%7C0.04022374821297813,41.6555680935796%7C0.0401938801374364,41.6555724697715%7C0.0401866339817127,41.655573531758705%7C0.04014841753011451,41.65559253940168%7C0.04012136158325442,41.65562480302526%7C0.04012063068125431,41.65562618352479%7C0.040102036266150255,41.65566131878862%7C0.040089356960466914,41.65569211977004%7C0.04005893316471178,41.65576602552929%7C0.040051750711455975,41.65580222361845%7C0.04004544165256271,41.655842947097426%7C0.040032126160390744,41.65587934802872%7C0.040015807432133406,41.655915760694654%7C0.03997528260426417,41.655979917461735%7C0.039961119701631055,41.65598799258771%7C0.03995049815329898,41.65599404851312%7C0.039942853857150906,41.6559942496788%7C0.03985371398798907,41.65599659745004%7C0.03980228933258589,41.65600247651727%7C0.03975174226249707,41.656012791287935%7C0.03970507517561764,41.65602752835093%7C0.03966397115820474,41.65604664160588%7C0.03963545676010589,41.65606094616271%7C0.039617866497061636,41.65608841114647%7C0.03961844149565348,41.65616497480735%7C0.03961414577002202,41.6562010672846%7C0.039597102845287495,41.65623755119668%7C0.03956400354588053,41.656265426893725%7C0.03952633359440169,41.65629345430321%7C0.039458177821080555,41.65634474149539%7C0.0394236686854761,41.65637717275709%7C0.03940910093689566,41.65639558109393%7C0.03939817512546034,41.656409386927464%7C0.03938098048826936,41.65644315007364%7C0.039379568975691136,41.65644592113097%7C0.03936309685859661,41.65647782684732%7C0.03934677310119708,41.656514330037794%7C0.03932541265788153,41.656568643097216%7C0.039303821712215053,41.65662354288986%7C0.03925695932698007,41.65669230970397%7C0.03923426867555194,41.65671936732721%7C0.039229902541929644,41.65672457332758%7C0.03919439679797868,41.65678399683367%7C0.039194100916779086,41.656824514956014%7C0.039190951835569844,41.65686964228718%7C0.03919596421396519,41.65689651886129%7C0.03922662018845202,41.65692720836341%7C0.039295667796323756,41.65696968449845%7C0.03930393654429534,41.65697477063759%7C0.03930853485664933,41.65697727682681%7C0.03934330215488685,41.65699622831099%7C0.039396235552950826,41.657026310125076%7C0.0395476487754374,41.65711235707178%7C0.03966764578477417,41.65719028782115%7C0.03969654491225152,41.65721413098436%7C0.039736377394877516,41.657246994752256%7C0.03979621748156652,41.657291811953%7C0.039811843864580615,41.65730351476691%7C0.03987315665174465,41.65736489293292%7C0.039900202540320305,41.65739576013138%7C0.03990380759708926,41.65740158639261%7C0.03994403067642632,41.65746659392292%7C0.03996293773653732,41.65750211391611%7C0.039985982104300384,41.657550193353785%7C0.039997026100577475,41.65757323688334%7C0.04004428075890426,41.65768459550276%7C0.04005657533520909,41.657720304926954%7C0.04006502261772887,41.65775609565563%7C0.040096527679057574,41.6578678582828%7C0.04011371812529672,41.657898920779616%7C0.040169337085296936,41.657958161560174%7C0.040171425855691785,41.65796038611745%7C0.04020865827179899,41.657986472278054%7C0.04022491162120769,41.65799241672411%7C0.04025448381554984,41.6580032327326%7C0.04025571427900875,41.65800344479476%7C0.040299878529452,41.65801106729796%7C0.04034742403983617,41.658000765100184%7C0.04052384467192559,41.65793758817762%7C0.040566616688169035,41.65792652238841%7C0.04091163679803233,41.65783725930527%7C0.0410018461981026,41.65780788324747%7C0.0410316874515526,41.657801838218546%7C0.04105311914104934,41.65779749723063%7C0.04106175166364024,41.6577980143941%7C0.04110581197847795,41.65780065553193%7C0.04113990704804105,41.65780873820165%7C0.04117413706625324,41.65783483693511%7C0.041195893973612424,41.65786583656762%7C0.04122952468571213,41.65789191937549%7C0.041266762130961546,41.65791791417334%7C0.04137407564366314,41.657976714065796%7C0.041394564368996876,41.65798793994935%7C0.041404999839067445,41.65799365808405%7C0.04141233987211226,41.657997679721404%7C0.04143147156724164,41.65800816296834%7C0.04147856696939867,41.65803060300087%7C0.0414794789205181,41.65803103718349%7C0.04148032633097924,41.65803144119124%7C0.0414911649706164,41.658036605282064%7C0.041556750014081593,41.65806785553352%7C0.04159884477250843,41.658084790331685%7C0.04174148968556461,41.65813502391859%7C0.04178860185152899,41.658147315142145%7C0.041837880739592354,41.65815948147531%7C0.04190665761197552,41.65818563888212%7C0.04192652272367613,41.65819319433007%7C0.04199795917409414,41.6582092632776%7C0.04205417995477795,41.658222021373206%7C0.04212590725725336,41.65823829819192%7C0.04219359029120745,41.658253657192205%7C0.04219840653305688,41.658254578363426%7C0.042251606475657615,41.65826475147992%7C0.04233834912036951,41.658281340105475%7C0.042386751261308864,41.658289070735236%7C0.042434450998720584,41.65828327464885%7C0.04244071647171477,41.658280066056136%7C0.042449364919922634,41.658275636220026%7C0.04246224203853262,41.658269040500016%7C0.042466747311755856,41.65826276832152%7C0.0424715836701741,41.658256035138294%7C0.042481994832724024,41.65824154115046%7C0.04248371396116697,41.65821447849808%7C0.04249443776872383,41.65810614490769%7C0.04251305816772927,41.658087623415156%7C0.04252125650771001,41.6581165426592%7C0.042528257073656144,41.658141238262004%7C0.04252997201114726,41.65817721506892%7C0.042525380404316214,41.65825391619305%7C0.04252770805896568,41.6583269493961%7C0.042530111988938565,41.65840236305979%7C0.042517528236957085,41.65856888801639%7C0.04251579402108752,41.65859183515411%7C0.042511053216371136,41.658633764789016%7C0.04250610789320516,41.65867749988601%7C0.04254461184409927,41.65862743226083%7C0.04255568350065848,41.658613035503095%7C0.042704411161208815,41.65841963983965%7C0.04389609658098795,41.656869663241935%7C0.043987920335705304,41.65675023201109%7C0.044215711140824024,41.656453861308336%7C0.0448310778189348,41.65671995154588%7C0.04495933435614909,41.65677541041151%7C0.04496666852186133,41.656778585476644%7C0.04500843722423537,41.656796666919234%7C0.045306469220308614,41.65692552527713%7C0.04549528584973728,41.65700716334251%7C0.045545746586218266,41.657028981437776%7C0.04558705093112892,41.65704683992175%7C0.04568211848256698,41.65708794393916%7C0.04574764988184867,41.65711627728814%7C0.04576830792163658,41.65712520904469%7C0.04580129155077288,41.65713947001558%7C0.0457895258725897,41.65711052897859%7C0.04577522969768819,41.65705288411249%7C0.04577237314491708,41.65699193174714%7C0.04578172818760443,41.65692901801643%7C0.045785033172221955,41.65690679256062%7C0.04581981304331499,41.65687886908674%7C0.045835246642544666,41.656861878968016%7C0.04584914970616399,41.6568465727737%7C0.04588982037915708,41.65681853027678%7C0.045990798849064034,41.65676628251842%7C0.04599208128032572,41.656765130006676%7C0.04599548600959694,41.65676206893548%7C0.046000725537581784,41.656757359143796%7C0.04600219404710496,41.65675603899396%7C0.046002961829481236,41.65675534916326%7C0.04600879479624598,41.656750106282544%7C0.04615034335630198,41.656622871499366%7C0.0461992794245052,41.656603146365455%7C0.04624594567319427,41.656588406787876%7C0.0464349617919303,41.65653842214354%7C0.046531061155710284,41.65650883318537%7C0.04661638809689212,41.65647059158803%7C0.04672136557304057,41.65639124848792%7C0.04680226351632258,41.6563395639935%7C0.04681761497289628,41.656332575162224%7C0.046844204885912226,41.65632047001694%7C0.04693414019773245,41.65628648894125%7C0.04697996238872184,41.65627181725705%7C0.047126162067124965,41.656236401199465%7C0.04721121408186638,41.65619364846165%7C0.0472491547688338,41.65617012883993%7C0.04725368099681621,41.65616549113261%7C0.04733935830157151,41.65607770745547%7C0.04737087928851719,41.65602779405734%7C0.0473798764239178,41.65601354733565%7C0.0473980157016525,41.65598699178841%7C0.04742684945028122,41.655944779683324%7C0.04744455622178651,41.65592366063885%7C0.04745390204437982,41.655912514383346%7C0.04748784204872501,41.65588456827834%7C0.04752534939127262,41.655852121091016%7C0.047538546698602836,41.6558445078079%7C0.04756629666708687,41.65582849753369%7C0.04761112476430087,41.655809297107%7C0.04765050797689009,41.65578572384109%7C0.047725545293125234,41.65573875165293%7C0.04775933023225249,41.65570629859829%7C0.04778409540483924,41.655674153997694%7C0.04780185246776655,41.65563768684939%7C0.047806942797866035,41.65561827519866%7C0.04781190739941044,41.65561704138247%7C0.04781096359705707,41.6556121924512%7C0.04783401467034309,41.655517336961935%7C%200.04786700165224085,41.6554508089543%7C0.047859350650569836,41.655290596409316%7C0.04779664311463493,41.65510650968815%7C%200.04767336794277238,41.65501912079867%7C0.04745843833064664,41.654971486440076%7C0.04732087117483444,41.654951105003136%7C%200.047169374133311154,41.6549079080244%7C0.04712811924163216,41.65490965481308%7C0.047008370336644074,41.6549907941552%7C%200.04684413950706359,41.65506236890701%7C0.04678805702779036,41.655060926381395%7C0.046692642465540314,41.655019170251876%7C%200.04661758922368819,41.654941443182764%7C0.04660133084513729,41.654887686681775%7C0.0466046643282273,41.654814781721825%7C%200.046499787434922904,41.65457065710103%7C0.04650519292460042,41.654534300593866%7C0.046667114539719494,41.65451319915135%7C%200.046984142444082645,41.65453819566446%7C0.047065498877495456,41.65455993832262%7C0.047178475204317276,41.65470882356297%7C%200.047246051788094746,41.65478635784831%7C0.04724850852406075,41.654814494222535%7C0.04725853244266107,41.65481555537153%7C%200.04725382432736899,41.654811863981166%7C0.047251745615258536,41.6548102345391%7C0.04728646094569332,41.654799684236934%7C%200.04731677158574888,41.65479047252478%7C0.04736320900846773,41.65477777226437%7C0.04740797256502346,41.65476552965586%7C%200.04742911591703391,41.65476109981975%7C0.04747934698935431,41.65475057633972%7C0.04749266751066849,41.65474778600395%7C%200.047493383325242,41.65474763596788%7C0.04749877624206401,41.654746506087264%7C0.04755576648150482,41.6547345669037%7C%200.04760358356556794,41.65472464692073%7C0.04760559186968755,41.654724230340065%7C0.04761344487523703,41.65472404929099%7C%200.047614034961255484,41.65472403587992%7C0.0476151380197786,41.654724009896%7C0.04761622850544622,41.65472398475029%7C%200.04762048735070153,41.654723886682035%7C0.04762115119747228,41.6547238715946%7C0.0476230496986538,41.65472382800871%7C%200.04762590708961529,41.654723761791644%7C0.0478007703640026,41.65471006492285%7C0.04784846255770102,41.65470435684648%7C%200.04789396204539906,41.65469408901447%7C0.04793521693707806,41.65467947935636%7C0.04802098644277373,41.654636745058696%7C%200.04802561912093276,41.65463492953836%7C0.048070382677488484,41.654617391243136%7C0.04811936484616189,41.654607123411154%7C%200.04815142730408473,41.65460315290338%7C0.04816573772822247,41.65460138013074%7C0.048209999208748286,41.654586668213426%7C%200.0482446240146234,41.6545796123269%7C0.048337147658297275,41.654560757234606%7C0.04849303849372496,41.654521229015074%7C%200.04849366881288103,41.6545210689207%7C0.04849580955107865,41.65452052661152%7C0.048506965864864936,41.65451811178508%7C%200.04848377313740689,41.65450714406413%7C0.04846406644368568,41.65449782674%7C0.04835557694989901,41.65444649680012%7C%200.048056706763458655,41.65431729394601%7C0.047935193467747765,41.65426476287928%7C0.04789959384647571,41.65424928150321%7C%200.047679226055248145,41.6541534461694%7C0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062&key=) (url whitout key and its gets error400)
26345 chars.

Is there a way to reduce it without removing precision?
Also i use ruby, if there is a solution that can be aplied with ruby would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Static Maps URL length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278053/google-static-maps-url-length-limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0.04096,41.65521&zoom=15&size=1200x800&path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7C0.03990083369766674,41.65117297365802%7C0.03986585098450487,41.6511738730363%7C0.0398193071116094,41.65118861345209%7C0.03978640897789055,41.651211227828185%7C0.039785212880236676,41.65121205009294%7C0.039761889395081365,41.65124414021116%7C0.03975127958141444,41.65127097990489%7C0.03973309671778063,41.65131697476312%7C0.039706482497244025,41.651425988964064%7C0.03969658765996025,41.65146652049745%7C0.039683272167788275,41.65150292059053%7C0.03968380609505212,41.65151410540278%7C0.03968455879000179,41.6515298809837%7C0.03969278143750318,41.65153853529924%7C0.03969588944738445,41.651541805918015%7C0.03971376972429572,41.65156062329174%7C0.039752407785648564,41.65158215221135%7C0.03979465677110295,41.65160350427274%7C0.03988602119749911,41.651632606242316%7C0.03992955596697664,41.65164948823451%7C0.03993958742929026,41.65165619711021%7C0.039968351608118506,41.651675434417314%7C0.03999355934521909,41.651701840766634%7C0.04000585559790465,41.65173745966629%7C0.04000155651951174,41.65177364266802%7C0.03998752269819514,41.65181002432095%7C0.03993384247251406,41.65191499844431%7C0.0399064931590255,41.65198778102845%7C0.03987869457550017,41.65209657478536%7C0.03987154648804941,41.65213727647139%7C0.03986267424301351,41.65216458136081%7C0.039847923768933036,41.65220997439829%7C0.03980755819723356,41.65227854926681%7C0.03978735697119576,41.65231062932676%7C0.0397695957173166,41.65234709479867%7C0.039757844288369676,41.65238344543852%7C0.03975297859328857,41.65242411611149%7C0.03975461138812371,41.65245838049552%7C0.039754692692589313,41.652460093756645%7C0.03976241996958375,41.65249586520693%7C0.039775312175620324,41.65253159055675%7C0.039792208417040606,41.65257165102716%7C0.0398126778639959,41.65260712072893%7C0.03984532034965278,41.652678297340344%7C0.039888420936520154,41.652749203216246%7C0.039899750755712435,41.652784978019326%7C0.03990246230155005,41.65282539304425%7C0.03990100971764384,41.65284035977143%7C0.03989973315371473,41.652853510978275%7C0.03989900644266644,41.65286150731441%7C0.03988340855812481,41.65289793925871%7C0.03982299431103434,41.65300310029855%7C0.03980279308499652,41.653035180358444%7C0.039796679324458795,41.65304764676378%7C0.03978491196989489,41.653071643315826%7C0.0397440929372068,41.65317631904341%7C0.0397286140756973,41.65321275350229%7C0.03970857042944851,41.65324925082547%7C0.03966616386420511,41.6533061086308%7C0.03966059408921564,41.6533135760688%7C0.03962721818698753,41.653337031149846%7C0.039608159414420085,41.65335700606448%7C0.03959644067489746,41.653369288906106%7C0.039574675385634625,41.65340141925745%7C0.03955691413175548,41.653437884729385%7C0.03954504200339567,41.653474232016464%7C0.03952742659464041,41.65350945529025%7C0.03952465972823856,41.65351498818487%7C0.03951080444147017,41.653542693729264%7C0.03949758031204822,41.6535615806728%7C0.03948831998487233,41.6535748056404%7C0.03938851917243118,41.65370353659338%7C0.039367413538987255,41.65375064205381%7C0.039358610025561444,41.653770290912405%7C0.039341569615398024,41.653808324638504%7C0.03932925156976292,41.65384916294957%7C0.039294849722525456,41.653976004621455%7C0.03927882436089661,41.65403509285139%7C0.03927713624549725,41.654056445750996%7C0.03927596780812548,41.65407122304717%7C0.039281407663608055,41.65410711603502%7C0.039310323554892744,41.654178376465495%7C0.03936399288409906,41.65425614795873%7C0.039382605739391195,41.65428311924833%7C0.03939218541709694,41.654297000518994%7C0.0394054858218423,41.65431627386832%7C0.03942630395599031,41.65434644117781%7C0.039450928312595376,41.6544222747749%7C0.03945708817360331,41.65445818620299%7C0.039456164487818746,41.654516564485675%7C0.03945594907289441,41.654530202681144%7C0.039453803305554584,41.65455188918051%7C0.03945192324456115,41.65457089514709%7C0.03943704788011598,41.65460725500702%7C0.03941627919919963,41.65464382357635%7C0.03934394253232732,41.654732627331185%7C0.0393319027658941,41.654747407980096%7C0.039311307590383746,41.65477269199252%7C0.03926260956824479,41.6548369987957%7C0.03925610688737672,41.65484747114613%7C0.03921995489865273,41.65490569352545%7C0.03921109941742416,41.65492864736862%7C0.0392059194009554,41.6549420751783%7C0.03919861708647711,41.65497826991475%7C0.03919375139139601,41.65501894058772%7C0.039193012107492216,41.655039557556165%7C0.03919245806365955,41.655055020492085%7C0.03919789791914211,41.655090913479995%7C0.03921464077172523,41.65512646783898%7C0.03923784355746767,41.65515732497917%7C0.03926289874392143,41.65517922521707%7C0.03928896814071942,41.655192054558825%7C0.03933606186649572,41.65518633390957%7C0.0394175440284636,41.655148178645845%7C0.039442782778607764,41.65513278192702%7C0.03945621058828894,41.65512459029256%7C0.039527098862206865,41.65506869053877%7C0.039586379037730636,41.65501163156773%7C0.039623324792732284,41.654976069665025%7C0.039725422246779336,41.654896838882365%7C0.03976381052740279,41.654868829913084%7C0.03980034640731491,41.65485428311925%7C0.039848573366467556,41.654835081854316%7C0.039941219385935034,41.654810092046716%7C0.039994916375423455,41.6547901758054%7C0.04003271457002846,41.654776157071524%7C0.04003523752303347,41.65477534486507%7C0.04007854095196967,41.65476139737734%7C0.04011864668465535,41.654737845904435%7C0.040155591601466624,41.654709888902886%7C0.040182720470888646,41.654686606489065%7C0.040188089918380375,41.654681998118434%7C0.040242230310573,41.65462206415444%7C0.04027888772808837,41.654571541391874%7C0.040315545145603725,41.6545210177911%7C0.04037410196284068,41.65445642432684%7C0.04040103721028788,41.65442415735046%7C0.040431813884187574,41.654391899594174%7C0.04046347317254383,41.65436398701678%7C0.04046785858454457,41.65436054037798%7C0.04047288018303395,41.65435659333954%7C0.040498973887352574,41.65433608282126%7C0.04050050609934366,41.65433434776722%7C0.04052434842433622,41.65430734714093%7C0.040555966641364495,41.65427153964842%7C0.04057773193062733,41.65423940929708%7C0.04060973320065338,41.65417113617707%7C0.04065305339339694,41.65410239115596%7C0.04065650087037687,41.6540996050112%7C0.04068771927060004,41.65407437631933%7C0.04072866319365282,41.65405084580112%7C0.040770455365357124,41.654027156026785%7C0.040860539036872326,41.65399777745441%7C0.040907804591673896,41.653983054640634%7C0.04095089763482795,41.65397290750806%7C0.04100058555979046,41.6539760792204%7C0.04104998095631486,41.65398824890633%7C0.04109435643073061,41.65400515185328%7C0.04114391192161512,41.65403052052292%7C0.04116956473780064,41.65404365328962%7C0.04119017248616651,41.65406561806819%7C0.04119417065421764,41.6541015638621%7C0.04119530388759398,41.65412534919008%7C0.04119588475351839,41.65413754066901%7C0.04120276964919386,41.65417338085089%7C0.04122281245725229,41.65419983413889%7C0.04124421732465728,41.654211061698874%7C0.04126361975527523,41.654221238168105%7C0.04131172601501501,41.654237967609646%7C0.04136353875255816,41.65424896382905%7C0.04138485477178423,41.65425348754249%7C0.04140638955869612,41.654258057356344%7C0.04145406834134867,41.65426576954596%7C0.04160685871060841,41.654275199187566%7C0.04165954987165629,41.65427835748889%7C0.04181220445407655,41.65426977106674%7C0.041937059614781114,41.65426650044793%7C0.04196128164000998,41.654265865937816%7C0.04198126661293308,41.65426063060079%7C0.04198913302952844,41.65425856949068%7C0.04198995948523041,41.654258353237566%7C0.04199706314859171,41.65425649161676%7C0.04201822074983839,41.654250948663844%7C0.04202009075254742,41.65425045916069%7C0.04202343094116037,41.65424958408994%7C0.042057054109546785,41.65424077554738%7C0.042151707594943494,41.65421124274798%7C0.04219497246712282,41.65419209345086%7C0.04220322026033522,41.65418708861617%7C0.04227241455152121,41.65414509695515%7C0.04227500791251706,41.65414385391884%7C0.042302370637051494,41.65413073875416%7C0.042353914315486796,41.6541248613633%7C0.042403152132222184,41.65413261378603%7C0.042413530605347784,41.654134562578605%7C0.042414217083258446,41.65413469165995%7C0.04243573091541116,41.65413873089932%7C0.042487086839204234,41.6541483734413%7C0.04250871131248541,41.654161268161914%7C0.04251341356044492,41.65417922052319%7C0.04249180752735182,41.65421576813779%7C0.04243910882259064,41.654275740658534%7C0.042402066675696765,41.6543058694113%7C0.04224077202697229,41.65443706045298%7C0.042230817678172446,41.654445157371924%7C0.042212416885043194,41.65446012326092%7C0.042203314137656336,41.654467526996456%7C0.042190945800599206,41.654477586957256%7C0.04216446569052133,41.65449912509689%7C0.042158375399313885,41.65450340238232%7C0.04212451502305359,41.65452718519583%7C0.04208356690904897,41.65455080623855%7C0.04195181511800379,41.65460378908983%7C0.04190542295756477,41.65462303729345%7C0.04185803335058887,41.654637846440835%7C0.04181464861718705,41.65465699238521%7C0.0416459468801884,41.6547380219244%7C0.041602715535623766,41.654761673980175%7C0.041584732161297336,41.6547697449152%7C0.0415343996679425,41.65479233414561%7C0.041517508455664424,41.65479991473927%7C0.041206645441451396,41.65492519234792%7C0.041072091580008956,41.654967805108015%7C0.041067007117242045,41.654969415271694%7C0.04098074475561051,41.65500777505386%7C0.0409415702524227,41.655031294675524%7C0.040926787088917914,41.655043202846116%7C0.04091264346466323,41.65505459552958%7C0.04090137650974849,41.65507725684432%7C0.04089677233006193,41.655086517171526%7C0.04089737917988772,41.65510847356819%7C0.04089776642383733,41.65512247553826%7C0.040903428399767176,41.65513149865757%7C0.04091724010063649,41.65515350702202%7C0.04094500934749897,41.655184301297936%7C%200.04096908636579433,41.65521968382788%7C0.04098133567981932,41.65523302865674%7C0.04105383830838432,41.65531201552599%7C%200.04109895139032312,41.655378379248276%7C0.04112916228572502,41.65541355977439%7C0.04115775631190874,41.65544364997035%7C%200.04118758834526468,41.65547504355237%7C0.04120909547189447,41.65548727945534%7C0.041225389892631165,41.65549654984082%7C%200.04127064379055165,41.655517888491175%7C0.04131000940114316,41.65553934616457%7C0.041343394523465304,41.655565511953284%7C%200.04137345119183965,41.65559618552976%7C0.04137836801653314,41.65560232024504%7C0.04139821468804566,41.65562708290304%7C%200.04142181226145102,41.65566441590201%7C0.04177131668977836,41.6555764746451%7C0.04208765141070791,41.65549688008781%7C%200.04280846076062087,41.655315512456184%7C0.04502639796742188,41.65475740088567%7C0.04503264248565688,41.65475582927874%7C%200.04491913726071341,41.65471054688234%7C0.04481832056154731,41.65463496222779%7C0.04490633893199795,41.65458509157733%7C%200.04516969080163186,41.654501499690184%7C0.0454428671005587,41.654456392475595%7C0.04567295370909296,41.65444145676145%7C%200.04576299295651871,41.65449938493592%7C0.04582947067272489,41.65455530648262%7C0.04584204604280269,41.65455214147582%7C%200.04669402212688459,41.6543377323799%7C0.04674658839756776,41.65432450405953%7C0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062%7C%200.04747183177452276,41.65406386792671%7C0.04745190379854463,41.6540552605498%7C0.04730123069815222,41.653990180935125%7C%200.04693486523240001,41.653832617071714%7C0.04660293514149995,41.653688814617794%7C0.046272875891499275,41.65354614120625%7C%200.04589455364016018,41.65338232192815%7C0.04559773953469034,41.65325319954027%7C0.04547678028281212,41.65320111690542%7C%200.04547537212299538,41.65320051089381%7C0.04545764355854056,41.65319287749412%7C0.04542093836417426,41.65317707257657%7C%200.0454185159940133,41.65317602902954%7C0.04540317375753365,41.653169423251285%7C0.04538960261729971,41.653163579388035%7C%200.04530522534580381,41.65312724886476%7C0.045198634353198666,41.65308073013756%7C0.044926965120551894,41.65296216727194%7C%200.044682048409852286,41.65285887288209%7C0.044474430332298885,41.65278022380352%7C0.04404397599288677,41.65262487360093%7C%200.043744324613024264,41.65251593567527%7C0.04336616161785493,41.652380391072825%7C0.04304298726352973,41.652263371315655%7C%200.04280758401349688,41.652177968937366%7C0.042621828455288904,41.6521115809075%7C0.042493676691870486,41.65206577967129%7C%200.04213919341276249,41.651937684904794%7C0.04190932641010441,41.65185728652298%7C0.04175594344025513,41.65180033484029%7C%200.041663035905393116,41.651765838277555%7C0.04139794143798598,41.65166988811163%7C0.041386050031247734,41.65166558400412%7C%200.04132406082445745,41.65164317163189%7C0.04112134448417094,41.651569877751626%7C0.041083383680634716,41.65155590847098%7C%200.040914122032470836,41.65149362003021%7C0.04079188789304423,41.65144863770598%7C0.04053546785774635,41.651355575105924%7C%200.04031697006922782,41.65127609705709%7C0.040218658721069014,41.65124693138503%7C0.040136785962390065,41.65122264230462%7C%200.04003391569682453,41.65119818390971%7C0.03995920862759403,41.6511804218176%7C0.03990083369766674,41.65117297365802%20&path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7C0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062%7C0.04674658839756776,41.65432450405953%7C0.04669402212688459,41.6543377323799%7C0.04584204604280269,41.65455214147582%7C0.04582947067272489,41.65455530648262%7C0.04595265951097963,41.65465893279591%7C0.04610042744355961,41.65482261628716%7C0.04614809197697591,41.654895094608236%7C0.045911219379229505,41.654906380003325%7C0.045561253108009875,41.65490780408874%7C0.045443292901265184,41.65490303143281%7C0.04522180361132643,41.654831294910224%7C0.04503264248565688,41.65475582927874%7C0.04502639796742188,41.65475740088567%7C0.04280846076062087,41.655315512456184%7C0.04208765141070791,41.65549688008781%7C0.04177131668977836,41.6555764746451%7C0.04142181226145102,41.65566441590201%7C0.0414310650449136,41.65567905489678%7C0.04144861088386839,41.65570681408536%7C0.041465396484160214,41.655733370470756%7C0.04149721083773439,41.655762378563%7C0.04149725945277568,41.65576451343384%7C0.04150375878088228,41.65605208229957%7C0.041496843710353594,41.656059615954575%7C0.041444482796310356,41.656116656485466%7C0.04141456275296585,41.656135429435096%7C0.04136614468640951,41.65614120624315%7C0.04132706825149465,41.65614227074488%7C0.04128124354593417,41.65612551029031%7C0.04119501722648842,41.65607768063336%7C0.04116495469078151,41.65606100567422%7C0.04112186332400818,41.656039632658064%7C0.04108033518226952,41.656018209350464%7C0.041008348878970674,41.655995706453695%7C0.040987399987125396,41.65598915767234%7C0.040937129519857736,41.655972462596594%7C0.040889723149074506,41.6559692598712%7C0.04078962477905301,41.65596289884451%7C0.04076305582079624,41.65595886211969%7C0.04074718720076604,41.65595645148423%7C0.0407389427603151,41.65595519838962%7C0.04072028045179132,41.65594841407679%7C0.04069311805475462,41.65593843793502%7C0.04065432325180311,41.65591240206584%7C0.04061847971713421,41.65588179722096%7C0.040587874034069424,41.65585566495989%7C0.04056173925842281,41.655836514824585%7C0.04055220568118726,41.65582952934605%7C0.04054751935884471,41.65582596871337%7C0.04051785663994292,41.655803428936224%7C0.0404244830712368,41.65571582798458%7C0.04030450534027847,41.655592959335024%7C0.04026526042909982,41.65557150501439%7C0.04022374821297813,41.6555680935796%7C0.0401938801374364,41.6555724697715%7C0.0401866339817127,41.655573531758705%7C0.04014841753011451,41.65559253940168%7C0.04012136158325442,41.65562480302526%7C0.04012063068125431,41.65562618352479%7C0.040102036266150255,41.65566131878862%7C0.040089356960466914,41.65569211977004%7C0.04005893316471178,41.65576602552929%7C0.040051750711455975,41.65580222361845%7C0.04004544165256271,41.655842947097426%7C0.040032126160390744,41.65587934802872%7C0.040015807432133406,41.655915760694654%7C0.03997528260426417,41.655979917461735%7C0.039961119701631055,41.65598799258771%7C0.03995049815329898,41.65599404851312%7C0.039942853857150906,41.6559942496788%7C0.03985371398798907,41.65599659745004%7C0.03980228933258589,41.65600247651727%7C0.03975174226249707,41.656012791287935%7C0.03970507517561764,41.65602752835093%7C0.03966397115820474,41.65604664160588%7C0.03963545676010589,41.65606094616271%7C0.039617866497061636,41.65608841114647%7C0.03961844149565348,41.65616497480735%7C0.03961414577002202,41.6562010672846%7C0.039597102845287495,41.65623755119668%7C0.03956400354588053,41.656265426893725%7C0.03952633359440169,41.65629345430321%7C0.039458177821080555,41.65634474149539%7C0.0394236686854761,41.65637717275709%7C0.03940910093689566,41.65639558109393%7C0.03939817512546034,41.656409386927464%7C0.03938098048826936,41.65644315007364%7C0.039379568975691136,41.65644592113097%7C0.03936309685859661,41.65647782684732%7C0.03934677310119708,41.656514330037794%7C0.03932541265788153,41.656568643097216%7C0.039303821712215053,41.65662354288986%7C0.03925695932698007,41.65669230970397%7C0.03923426867555194,41.65671936732721%7C0.039229902541929644,41.65672457332758%7C0.03919439679797868,41.65678399683367%7C0.039194100916779086,41.656824514956014%7C0.039190951835569844,41.65686964228718%7C0.03919596421396519,41.65689651886129%7C0.03922662018845202,41.65692720836341%7C0.039295667796323756,41.65696968449845%7C0.03930393654429534,41.65697477063759%7C0.03930853485664933,41.65697727682681%7C0.03934330215488685,41.65699622831099%7C0.039396235552950826,41.657026310125076%7C0.0395476487754374,41.65711235707178%7C0.03966764578477417,41.65719028782115%7C0.03969654491225152,41.65721413098436%7C0.039736377394877516,41.657246994752256%7C0.03979621748156652,41.657291811953%7C0.039811843864580615,41.65730351476691%7C0.03987315665174465,41.65736489293292%7C0.039900202540320305,41.65739576013138%7C0.03990380759708926,41.65740158639261%7C0.03994403067642632,41.65746659392292%7C0.03996293773653732,41.65750211391611%7C0.039985982104300384,41.657550193353785%7C0.039997026100577475,41.65757323688334%7C0.04004428075890426,41.65768459550276%7C0.04005657533520909,41.657720304926954%7C0.04006502261772887,41.65775609565563%7C0.040096527679057574,41.6578678582828%7C0.04011371812529672,41.657898920779616%7C0.040169337085296936,41.657958161560174%7C0.040171425855691785,41.65796038611745%7C0.04020865827179899,41.657986472278054%7C0.04022491162120769,41.65799241672411%7C0.04025448381554984,41.6580032327326%7C0.04025571427900875,41.65800344479476%7C0.040299878529452,41.65801106729796%7C0.04034742403983617,41.658000765100184%7C0.04052384467192559,41.65793758817762%7C0.040566616688169035,41.65792652238841%7C0.04091163679803233,41.65783725930527%7C0.0410018461981026,41.65780788324747%7C0.0410316874515526,41.657801838218546%7C0.04105311914104934,41.65779749723063%7C0.04106175166364024,41.6577980143941%7C0.04110581197847795,41.65780065553193%7C0.04113990704804105,41.65780873820165%7C0.04117413706625324,41.65783483693511%7C0.041195893973612424,41.65786583656762%7C0.04122952468571213,41.65789191937549%7C0.041266762130961546,41.65791791417334%7C0.04137407564366314,41.657976714065796%7C0.041394564368996876,41.65798793994935%7C0.041404999839067445,41.65799365808405%7C0.04141233987211226,41.657997679721404%7C0.04143147156724164,41.65800816296834%7C0.04147856696939867,41.65803060300087%7C0.0414794789205181,41.65803103718349%7C0.04148032633097924,41.65803144119124%7C0.0414911649706164,41.658036605282064%7C0.041556750014081593,41.65806785553352%7C0.04159884477250843,41.658084790331685%7C0.04174148968556461,41.65813502391859%7C0.04178860185152899,41.658147315142145%7C0.041837880739592354,41.65815948147531%7C0.04190665761197552,41.65818563888212%7C0.04192652272367613,41.65819319433007%7C0.04199795917409414,41.6582092632776%7C0.04205417995477795,41.658222021373206%7C0.04212590725725336,41.65823829819192%7C0.04219359029120745,41.658253657192205%7C0.04219840653305688,41.658254578363426%7C0.042251606475657615,41.65826475147992%7C0.04233834912036951,41.658281340105475%7C0.042386751261308864,41.658289070735236%7C0.042434450998720584,41.65828327464885%7C0.04244071647171477,41.658280066056136%7C0.042449364919922634,41.658275636220026%7C0.04246224203853262,41.658269040500016%7C0.042466747311755856,41.65826276832152%7C0.0424715836701741,41.658256035138294%7C0.042481994832724024,41.65824154115046%7C0.04248371396116697,41.65821447849808%7C0.04249443776872383,41.65810614490769%7C0.04251305816772927,41.658087623415156%7C0.04252125650771001,41.6581165426592%7C0.042528257073656144,41.658141238262004%7C0.04252997201114726,41.65817721506892%7C0.042525380404316214,41.65825391619305%7C0.04252770805896568,41.6583269493961%7C0.042530111988938565,41.65840236305979%7C0.042517528236957085,41.65856888801639%7C0.04251579402108752,41.65859183515411%7C0.042511053216371136,41.658633764789016%7C0.04250610789320516,41.65867749988601%7C0.04254461184409927,41.65862743226083%7C0.04255568350065848,41.658613035503095%7C0.042704411161208815,41.65841963983965%7C0.04389609658098795,41.656869663241935%7C0.043987920335705304,41.65675023201109%7C0.044215711140824024,41.656453861308336%7C0.0448310778189348,41.65671995154588%7C0.04495933435614909,41.65677541041151%7C0.04496666852186133,41.656778585476644%7C0.04500843722423537,41.656796666919234%7C0.045306469220308614,41.65692552527713%7C0.04549528584973728,41.65700716334251%7C0.045545746586218266,41.657028981437776%7C0.04558705093112892,41.65704683992175%7C0.04568211848256698,41.65708794393916%7C0.04574764988184867,41.65711627728814%7C0.04576830792163658,41.65712520904469%7C0.04580129155077288,41.65713947001558%7C0.0457895258725897,41.65711052897859%7C0.04577522969768819,41.65705288411249%7C0.04577237314491708,41.65699193174714%7C0.04578172818760443,41.65692901801643%7C0.045785033172221955,41.65690679256062%7C0.04581981304331499,41.65687886908674%7C0.045835246642544666,41.656861878968016%7C0.04584914970616399,41.6568465727737%7C0.04588982037915708,41.65681853027678%7C0.045990798849064034,41.65676628251842%7C0.04599208128032572,41.656765130006676%7C0.04599548600959694,41.65676206893548%7C0.046000725537581784,41.656757359143796%7C0.04600219404710496,41.65675603899396%7C0.046002961829481236,41.65675534916326%7C0.04600879479624598,41.656750106282544%7C0.04615034335630198,41.656622871499366%7C0.0461992794245052,41.656603146365455%7C0.04624594567319427,41.656588406787876%7C0.0464349617919303,41.65653842214354%7C0.046531061155710284,41.65650883318537%7C0.04661638809689212,41.65647059158803%7C0.04672136557304057,41.65639124848792%7C0.04680226351632258,41.6563395639935%7C0.04681761497289628,41.656332575162224%7C0.046844204885912226,41.65632047001694%7C0.04693414019773245,41.65628648894125%7C0.04697996238872184,41.65627181725705%7C0.047126162067124965,41.656236401199465%7C0.04721121408186638,41.65619364846165%7C0.0472491547688338,41.65617012883993%7C0.04725368099681621,41.65616549113261%7C0.04733935830157151,41.65607770745547%7C0.04737087928851719,41.65602779405734%7C0.0473798764239178,41.65601354733565%7C0.0473980157016525,41.65598699178841%7C0.04742684945028122,41.655944779683324%7C0.04744455622178651,41.65592366063885%7C0.04745390204437982,41.655912514383346%7C0.04748784204872501,41.65588456827834%7C0.04752534939127262,41.655852121091016%7C0.047538546698602836,41.6558445078079%7C0.04756629666708687,41.65582849753369%7C0.04761112476430087,41.655809297107%7C0.04765050797689009,41.65578572384109%7C0.047725545293125234,41.65573875165293%7C0.04775933023225249,41.65570629859829%7C0.04778409540483924,41.655674153997694%7C0.04780185246776655,41.65563768684939%7C0.047806942797866035,41.65561827519866%7C0.04781190739941044,41.65561704138247%7C0.04781096359705707,41.6556121924512%7C0.04783401467034309,41.655517336961935%7C%200.04786700165224085,41.6554508089543%7C0.047859350650569836,41.655290596409316%7C0.04779664311463493,41.65510650968815%7C%200.04767336794277238,41.65501912079867%7C0.04745843833064664,41.654971486440076%7C0.04732087117483444,41.654951105003136%7C%200.047169374133311154,41.6549079080244%7C0.04712811924163216,41.65490965481308%7C0.047008370336644074,41.6549907941552%7C%200.04684413950706359,41.65506236890701%7C0.04678805702779036,41.655060926381395%7C0.046692642465540314,41.655019170251876%7C%200.04661758922368819,41.654941443182764%7C0.04660133084513729,41.654887686681775%7C0.0466046643282273,41.654814781721825%7C%200.046499787434922904,41.65457065710103%7C0.04650519292460042,41.654534300593866%7C0.046667114539719494,41.65451319915135%7C%200.046984142444082645,41.65453819566446%7C0.047065498877495456,41.65455993832262%7C0.047178475204317276,41.65470882356297%7C%200.047246051788094746,41.65478635784831%7C0.04724850852406075,41.654814494222535%7C0.04725853244266107,41.65481555537153%7C%200.04725382432736899,41.654811863981166%7C0.047251745615258536,41.6548102345391%7C0.04728646094569332,41.654799684236934%7C%200.04731677158574888,41.65479047252478%7C0.04736320900846773,41.65477777226437%7C0.04740797256502346,41.65476552965586%7C%200.04742911591703391,41.65476109981975%7C0.04747934698935431,41.65475057633972%7C0.04749266751066849,41.65474778600395%7C%200.047493383325242,41.65474763596788%7C0.04749877624206401,41.654746506087264%7C0.04755576648150482,41.6547345669037%7C%200.04760358356556794,41.65472464692073%7C0.04760559186968755,41.654724230340065%7C0.04761344487523703,41.65472404929099%7C%200.047614034961255484,41.65472403587992%7C0.0476151380197786,41.654724009896%7C0.04761622850544622,41.65472398475029%7C%200.04762048735070153,41.654723886682035%7C0.04762115119747228,41.6547238715946%7C0.0476230496986538,41.65472382800871%7C%200.04762590708961529,41.654723761791644%7C0.0478007703640026,41.65471006492285%7C0.04784846255770102,41.65470435684648%7C%200.04789396204539906,41.65469408901447%7C0.04793521693707806,41.65467947935636%7C0.04802098644277373,41.654636745058696%7C%200.04802561912093276,41.65463492953836%7C0.048070382677488484,41.654617391243136%7C0.04811936484616189,41.654607123411154%7C%200.04815142730408473,41.65460315290338%7C0.04816573772822247,41.65460138013074%7C0.048209999208748286,41.654586668213426%7C%200.0482446240146234,41.6545796123269%7C0.048337147658297275,41.654560757234606%7C0.04849303849372496,41.654521229015074%7C%200.04849366881288103,41.6545210689207%7C0.04849580955107865,41.65452052661152%7C0.048506965864864936,41.65451811178508%7C%200.04848377313740689,41.65450714406413%7C0.04846406644368568,41.65449782674%7C0.04835557694989901,41.65444649680012%7C%200.048056706763458655,41.65431729394601%7C0.047935193467747765,41.65426476287928%7C0.04789959384647571,41.65424928150321%7C%200.047679226055248145,41.6541534461694%7C0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062&key=) you provided, [encoding the paths](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#EncodedPolylines) of the polygons works.

I used a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q8v61odw/2/) and the Google Maps Javascript API to encode the paths.  Resulting [live static map](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20220113_staticmap.html) (zoomed out some to give context).

The encoding algorithm is described [in the Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) and   there is [at least one ruby implementation](https://github.com/joshuaclayton/polylines)
[image: screenshot of resulting static map]

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0.04096,41.65521&zoom=12&size=1200x800&path=fillcolor:red%7Cweight:1%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:kxFy~e}FD?HCDC??DE@EBIBU@GBE?A?CAAA?ACGCGCSEGCAAECCCCG@E@GJSBODU@G@C@IFMBEBG@E@G?G??AGCEAGCGGMGMAE?I?A?A?ABGJSBG?ABCFU@EBGFK@?DEBC@ADE@G@EBG@?@E@C@ARYBI@CBG@GFY@K?C?A?GEMIOCCACCCCECMAG?K?A@C?C@GBENQ@CBCHM?AFK@C?A@G@G?C?CAEAGEECCEAI?OFCBC@MHKJEDUNEDGBI@QDIBG@A?GBGBGDCBA@IJGHGHIJEFEDEDA???EB?@CBGFCDELGLA?EDGBGBQDIBG@IAIAGCICEACE?EAE?A?ECECACAICIAC?EAGA_@AI?]@Y?C?C@A???A?C@????G@QDGBA?MFA@C@I@IAA???EAIACA?CBGHKFE^Y@ABA@A@ADC??FEFCXIFCHCHC^OHCBAHC@A|@YZG??PGFC@ABA@E?A?C?A?ACCEECGAAMOIMEEEEEGCACAGCGCEEEEA?CECEeAN_ANoCb@{LnB??THRNQFs@Pu@Fm@BQKMKA@iDh@KBgDh@VHB?\LhA^`AZ`AZjA`@x@XVH??B@F@??B@@@NDTHt@Vp@Rh@NtA^z@RhAZ`AVl@Nd@LXFdAXl@N\JRDr@R@?LDf@LF@`@LVFp@Pj@NRDNDTBLBJ@&path=fillcolor:red%7Cweight:1%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:mhHeqf}FfDi@JChDi@@AWS]_@IOn@AdA?V@j@Ld@L??zLoBnCc@~@OdAOACCECCEE???y@?AJKDCF?F?H@NHFBFBFBLBB@HBH?R@D?@?@?B@D@FDDDDBDB@@??DDRNVXDBH?D???FCDE?ABE@EDO@E?GBG@GFKBA@?@?PAH?HAFCHCBABE?M@G@GFEDCLIFG@C@ABE?ABE@EBKDIFMDE??FK?G?IAEEEMG??AAECKE]OWOECGGKGAAKKEG??GMCEEIACGUCGAGEUAEKK??GEA?EAA?GAI@a@JI@cAPQDE@C?A?I?EAECEGECGESKCAA?AACAIC????AAMEGA[KIAIAMEC?MCIAOCKAA?IAQCIAG@A?A?A@A@??AB?DARCBAEAC?G?M?O?M@a@?C@G?IEHCB[d@oFtHQVm@z@yBu@YKA?GC{@Ye@OICGCQGMECAEA@D@J@JAJABEDCBA@GDSH??A@??????A@[XIBI@c@HSDQFSNOHC@C@QDIB]DOHGB??QPEHABCBEHABA@GDGDA@E@GBGBOHEDCFCDAB???@CPGL@^Jb@XPh@HZB\FF?VO`@MH?RFLNBH?NRn@AF_@B}@EQCU]MO?CAA@@??G@E@G@I@C@I@A???A?KBG@A?????A?????????A?a@@I@G@I@OFA@G@I@E@C?G@E@SB]F??A?A?D@B@RHz@XVJF@j@RPF&key=AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg'
    alt='static map' />
</body>

</html>
```